# SQL Limit Offset pagination turn to Cursor based pagination

Tags: sql

I try to understand how to pagination work and as far as i understand Limit Offset pagination it is not the best way to use pagination (main reason is that the database is always dynamically changed).

I wonder how to turn **Limit Offset pagination** to **Cursor based pagination**

below is what i did for limit offset pagination (works fine)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY orders.id ) as rn,
           orders.id, res.id
           FROM orders_order orders
           JOIN reserves_reserve res on res.order_id=orders.id
    ) as orders
WHERE rn BETWEEN 10 and 15;
```

How to turn it to Cursor based pagination?

Comment: That's not LIMIT OFFSET pagination...  Why would you WANT to resort to cursors *(which could involve every user of your application holiding open a cursor on the database server!?)*?  Have you considered `ORDER BY orders.id OFFSET 10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY` or the equivalent in your database?  *(SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc, have varying syntax and you should specify **which you're using**.)*

Comment: i use postgres. i want to use cursor, because it will be  attract all new rows if there are since start  of pagination pagination process.

Answer (score 0):

> Offset pagination it is not the best way to use pagination (main reason is that the database is always dynamically changed).

It depends on how big the offset could be. In most relational databases, OFFSET ends up loading all the records filtered from `0` to `OFFSET + limit` in memory and discards the first `(0, OFFSET)` records. In other words, the bigger offset, the slower the query is.

Cursor-based pagination uses where clauses without offset, without having to load all the records filtered in memory. However, it requires the server to know the cursor to get the next page. There is no way to jump between pages.

I suggest reading [this post](https://ignaciochiazzo.medium.com/paginating-requests-in-apis-d4883d4c1c4c) that contains more information about the pros and cons of both approaches.

Note that the query you posted doesn't use offset pagination. As an example, I will use a more straightforward query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM orders JOIN reserves_reserve res on res.order_id=orders.id
WHERE orders.status = "fulfilled" AND res.created_at > 15
ORDER_BY orders.id
OFFSET 10
LIMIT 10
```

You can turn this into cursor base pagination by iterating over the id

```sql
SELECT *
FROM orders JOIN reserves_reserve res on res.order_id=orders.id
WHERE orders.status = "fulfilled" AND res.created_at > 15 AND
  orders.id > 123
ORDER_BY orders.id
LIMIT 10
```

Note that this requires the server to know the cursor. In the case example, the cursor contains the latest `order.id` (123) which we will use as part of the where clause.